# Single use Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to add a dynamic link to a Flutter app but I need this link to work only once when generated as this will be a sharing option that might contain data I do not want to be lingering around for long after. I have been trying to find any docs on how to do this but have not been able to find anything that explains how to do this.

Is there any way to generate this single use link? Or does anyone have any recommendations on a way to implement this? Making sure a link gets used once and only once?